# Which species has dominanted the univese for the longest in star wars

Tags: star-wars

So, its my understanding that humans are the most dominant species in Star Wars in the current time line.

This quote:

> "What manner of creature would have birthed such a thing? Nothing human, to be sure." ―Kreia, to Bao-Dur

Got me to thinking, if she doesn't think that humans could have created (considering we created the DS) could it be that there were more powerful species previously that might have created such weapons?

Comment: "Humans" are a species, not a race, btw.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but where was this quote from? I'm assuming it was legends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Celestials](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial).** Exact timeframe is unknown but HUGE. Power area unknown but probably entire galaxy.

Runners up would be [Kwa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kwa), and then [Rakata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Empire) (and [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rakata)), possibly [Columi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Columi).

[Killiks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Killik) were always under Celestial's control so they don't count as "Dominant".

Mandalorians would be runner ups, except that biologically, their power was when they already were multi-species and mostly human as opposed to Taung.

Other galaxies had other powers (e.g. Vong galaxy).

Comment: So humans did co-exist with the celestials :) Nice to know indeed.

Comment: @JamieHutber - Anakin Skywalker supposedly met The Ones who were Celestials.